# spaCy: Is it possible to convert json format (with BILUO scheme) files to list format that is used for training in Python?

Tags: python, json, nlp, spacy

I would like to do some evaluation of spaCy's pretrained models with the wikiner datasets. However, these datasets are in json format, using the BILUO annotation scheme. I know that I can do evaluation in the command-line interface, but I would like to do it in the Python interpreter instead, which requires a different data format, as shown below.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [("Dogs are loyal", {'entities': [(0, 4, 'ANIMAL)]})]
```

I wonder if there is a way to convert the BILUO scheme json formatted data into the format below. OR alternatively, is it possible to directly evaluate data that is in json format (e.g., I could read json files into the Python interpreter.)

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Added sample json data set

```
[
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"Zum",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":"1.",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":"Januar",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":"1994",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":"wird",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":"Ruppendorf",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-LOC"
              },
              {
                "orth":"nach",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":"H\u00f6ckendorf",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-LOC"
              },
              {
                "orth":"eingemeindet",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":".",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Spacy can handle many of the relevant conversions with `spacy convert`, but from the information in your question I'm not exactly sure what your data looks like. Can you give examples of the data format and what your evaluation code looks like?

Comment: @aab See the added sample data set. It was basically from one of wikiner files here: https://github.com/dice-group/FOX/tree/master/input/Wikiner

I can run evaluation on it just fine in windows command line interface, but I need to do a bit of more fine-grained analysis of the results, which is much more convenient if I can do it in Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial caveat: you are probably aware of this, but many of spacy's non-English NER models are trained on WikiNER, so be aware that you might accidentally be evaluating on the training data, which obviously won't give you a good picture of how well the model works.

If you have spacy's internal JSON training format with BILUO NER tags and you would like to have entity spans referenced by character offsets, you can load the data with `GoldCorpus` and convert it to offsets with `spacy.gold.offsets_from_biluo_tags`. Note that with this kind of input with no provided `raw` text for each paragraph you will have a space between each token when counting character offsets.

```python
import spacy
from spacy.gold import GoldCorpus, offsets_from_biluo_tags

nlp = spacy.load('de')
goldcorpus = GoldCorpus("/path/to/train.json", "/path/to/train.json")

train_docs = goldcorpus.train_docs(nlp)
for doc, gold in train_docs:
    print(doc.text)
    print(offsets_from_biluo_tags(doc, gold.ner))
```

Output:

```
Zum 1. Januar 1994 wird Ruppendorf nach Höckendorf eingemeindet .
[(24, 34, 'LOC'), (40, 50, 'LOC')]
```

Notes:

- `GoldCorpus.train_docs()` needs the `nlp` model in order to handle cases where the tokenization in your corpus vs. spacy are not the same.
- `GoldCorpus` always expects to have both train and dev data provided as `GoldCorpus(train_path, dev_path)`, so loading the train data for both doesn't cause any problems as long as you're not using the dev data for anything.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and code. Yes, I am aware that some of the non-English NER models are trained on WikiNER data. My plan is to actually train on a subset of the data using a blank `xx` model, and then evaluate on the remaining. So if that is my plan, for the `GoldCorpus` function, should I still provide the `train_path` for both arguments, or should I provide the `dev_path` for the 2nd arg? I was going to read in the full json file using `GoldCorpus`, and then do train/dev/test split.

Comment: Hmm, I initially thought it didn't matter, but looking more closely I think that `train_docs()` has some extra options and does some shuffling that `dev_docs()` doesn't when there are multiple train files. (You can provide a directory with json files instead of one single file.) If you just have one file, then I don't think it matters, but if you have multiple files and don't want a different order with `train_docs()` each time, then use `dev_docs()`. And then do the splits/shuffling as you want for your task. Let me also think about whether you can do your task without so many conversions...

Comment: Right now, all my annotated data is in one file, but I do anticipate that there will be data split amongst several files if the dataset is sufficiently large. So if there is a way do without many conversions, that would be great!

Comment: I would use `goldcorpus.dev_docs()` from the path in the second GoldCorpus argument then, since it doesn't do any additional preprocessing. (It's more of an issue for parsing than NER.) You can provide a path to a directory and it will find all the `.json` files in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For Spacy3 several changes are made. I would like to update the import and code here. The input data are no long json format but binary spacy format. So it is to convert train.spacy to the desired format.

```
import spacy
from spacy.training import Corpus, biluo_tags_to_offsets


nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")

corpus = Corpus(path/to/train.spacy)

train_data = corpus(nlp)

for example in  train_data:
    print(example.text)
    print(biluo_tags_to_offsets(example.reference, example.get_aligned_ner()))
```

Here are some docs related to [Spacy Example](https://spacy.io/api/example#reference) ,[Spacy biluo](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#biluo_tags_to_offsets) and [Corpus](https://spacy.io/api/corpus).